# Lifting back the induced invariant measure / general version of Kac's formula for occupation times

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $T$ be a conservative measure preserving (non-invertible!) transformation of a measure space $(X, \mathscr{F}, m)$ with *infinite* measure $m$. Let $A \in \mathscr{F}$ be such that $X = \cup_{k=0}^\infty T^{-k} A \pmod{m}$ and $0<m(A)<\infty$. Then the first hitting time $\tau(x):= \inf\{k \ge 1: T^k x \in A\}$ is finite $m$-a.e. $x \in X$ and the induced transformation $T_A$ defined by $T_A(x) := T^{\tau(x)} x$ for $x \in A$ is measure preserving on $(A, \mathscr{F} \cap A, m|_A)$.

I am trying to prove that the invariant measure $m|_A$ of the induced transformation can be lifted back to $m$ as follows:
$$
m(B)=\int_A \sum_{k=0}^{\tau(x)-1} \mathbb 1(T^k x \in B) m|_A(dx), \qquad B \in \mathscr{F}.
$$
This is Lemma 1.5.4 of Aaronson's *Introduction to Infinite Ergodic Theory* but I do not understand the proof given, something is strange there. Is this statement actually true? Any hints or references please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find a reference and eventually proved the statement by myself, see Lemma A.3 (in the Appendix) of my paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.05010 
The idea of the proof reminds that of Aaronson's.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the question you ask has nothing to do with the finiteness (or not) of the measure $m$ as being measure preserving is a **local property** (it is formulated in terms of finite measure subsets). The relation between induced transformations and suspensions (these two operations are inverse to each other) is precisely the same no matter whether the state spaces are of finite measure or not.

You have already defined the induced transformation and formulated the fact that the restriction of an invariant measure is invariant under the induced transformation. Let me just mention that there is no need to specify anything concerning the measures of the state space $X$ and of the recurrent subset $A$; the only necessary assumption is that the hitting times are a.e. finite.

Conversely, given a measure preserving transformation $T:X\to X$ and an integer valued **roof function** $r$ one defines the **suspension** $\tilde T$ acting on the space 
$$
\tilde X = \{(x,n):1\le n \le r(x)  \}
$$
as 
$$
\tilde T(x,n) =
\begin{cases}
(x,n+1)\;,& n< r(x) \\
(Tx,1) \;, & n=r(x)
\end{cases}
$$ 
If $m$ is a measure on $X$, let $\tilde m$ denote the measure on $\tilde X$ obtained by integrating the counting measures on the fibers of the projection $\tilde X\to X$ with respect to $m$. If $m$ is $T$-invariant, then $\tilde m$ is $\tilde T$-invariant (the easiest way to check this is to look just at the subsets of $\tilde X$ of the form $A\times\{n\}$, where $A$ is a subset of $X$). This is precisely what you are asking about in the particular case when the roof function is the first return time.

PS Aaronson's book is written in a very dense formal style.

Comment: Thank you for this response, it gave me some new ideas and made me look for more references. In short, it seems to me that we are talking about two different types of inducing (compared in Sec. 1.3.E of Petersen's Ergodic Theory). Your explanation gives invariance under T of the measure in the RHS of the Kac formula. This measure is always invariant if m|_A is invariant for T_A. But I don't see why it equals m as I want.

Comment: Further, m|_A is not always invariant for the induced transformation T_A in the meaning I need, see this [example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283733/are-induced-transformations-always-measure-preserving-on-infinite-measure-spaces)

Comment: The Surrey notes of Roland Zweimuller (http://mat.univie.ac.at/~zweimueller/MyPub/SurreyNotes.pdf) make a nice presentation of this in Proposition 3.

Comment: Thank you, I saw these notes. Proposition 3 just proves invariance of the RHS but not that it is equal to the initial invariant measure m.

Comment: @Vysotsky 1.There are no "two types of inducing". What Petersen misleadingly calls the "second kind of induced transformation" in Section 1.3.E is precisely the suspension (or "special transformation") determined by the roof function $r(x)=\max\{n:x\in Y_n\}$ and what he himself considered (in the case of a continuous roof function) in the previous Section 1.3.D under the name of "flow under a function". 2. The example you quote is not applicable in this situation as you explicitly assumed that $T$ is **conservative**.

Comment: @RW Thank you. 1. I agree, but I need the "first kind" but not the "second". Sorry, but I really don't see your argument. Is "your" X exactly my "A"? If so, then the RHS of Kac's formula is just f_B(x,n)=1_(T^n x \in B) integrated over \tilde{m}. And invariance of \tilde{m} is equivalent to invariance of m|_A. Inducing the former on the ground level of \tilde{X} gives the latter. But why this gives any information about the measure m on ("my") X? 2. Ok, I mistook your claim that there is not need to specify anything other than finiteness of the hitting time. I agree "under conservativity".

Comment: The point is that the operations of inducing (taking the trace of a transformation on a recurrent subset) and of suspension invert each other. In particular, if you first take in induced transformation and then suspend it by using the first return time function, then you recover the original transformation (by a transformation I means the whole triple consisting of the state space, the measure and the transformation).

Comment: @RW Yes, this is how I always thought this should be. But I really don't see how this follows from your explanation. Does your suspension act on the tilded space constructed over A (the subset of X) or over the whole X?

Comment: @Vysotsky If $r$ is the first return time to a subset $A$, then the space $\tilde A$ determined by $r$ is precisely $X$. What exactly is not clear in my argument?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77724/discussion-between-vysotsky-and-r-w).